# How to replace each field delimiter of a delimited string (e.g. comma to semicolon) using regex and javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to replace every other comma in a string with a semicolon.

For example:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

would become

```
1;2,3;4,5;6,7;8,9;10
```

What would be the regexp to do this? An explanation would be great.

Thank you :)

Comment: Your example replaces all commas. But you seem to suggest in the question that some commas should not be replaced.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You mention that you want to replace the first pair (two) commas, but then mention the first comma (one). Your example then shows all commas being replaced with a semicolon. I recommend you update your example to reflect the initial data as well as the proper result to remove the abiguity from your question.

Comment: Do you mean "every second comma beginning with the first"? ("Every odd comma"?) You talk about pairs of commas yet in your example your string has an odd number of commas such that the one between 9 and 10 is not part of a pair yet you replace it anyway. Step one in solving a problem is understanding what the problem is...

Answer (score 4):

```
var myNums = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
myNums.replace(/(.*?),(.*?,)?/g,"$1;$2");
```

That'll do it.

Comment: wow, people on stackoverflow are really quick at answering! thanks alot! this works a treat, but how does it work?

Comment: @Steve basically every time you place a part of a regex in a `()` grouping, it creates a [backtrace](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that you can later reference with $1 through $9 (I think?).  So the regex is basically "0 or more characters followed by a comma followed by 0 or more characters followed by a comma.  The last '0 or more followed by a comma' is optional.  The '0 or more' sets are [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).  Lastly, search globally".  Then it replaces the groups (which does not include the second comma) with themselves and a ;

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10';
str.replace(/,(.*?,)?/g, ';$1');

// Now str === "1;2,3;4,5;6,7;8,9;10"
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:

```
 myString.replace(/,/g, ';');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but from what i know that would replace every comma with a semi colon, im looking to replace a comma, leave a comma,replace a comma..etc

Comment: I had the same answer, not noticing... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex pattern

```
([^,]*),([^,]*),?
```

And replace with `$1;$2,`. The question mark on the end is to account for the lack of a comma signaling the end of the last pair.

For example...

```
var theString = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
theString = theString.replace(/([^,]*),([^,]*),?/ig, "$1;$2,"); //returns "1;2,3;4,5;6,7;8,9;10,"
theString = theString.substring(0, theString.length - 1); //returns "1;2,3;4,5;6,7;8,9;10"
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-regex answer:

```
function alternateDelims(array, delim_one, delim_two) {
    var delim = delim_one,
        len = array.length,
        result = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        result.push(array[i]);
        if(i < len-1) { result.push(delim); }
        delim = (delim === delim_one) ? delim_two : delim_one;
    }

    return result.join('');
}

nums = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
alternateDelims(nums.split(','), ';', ',');
```

Comment: You could make this shorter (not that shorter is always better) by dropping the `delim` variable and saying `result.push(i%2==0?delim_one:delim_two);`